# Sanic: difference between request.ip and request.remote_addr?

Tags: python-3.x, http, request, ip, sanic

What is the difference between ip an remote_addr attributes of Sanic request?

Source code of [Sanic framework](https://github.com/huge-success/sanic/blob/v19.12.2/sanic/request.py):

```
@property
def ip(self):
    """
    :return: peer ip of the socket
    """
    if not hasattr(self, "_socket"):
        self._get_address()
    return self._ip


@property
def remote_addr(self):
    """Attempt to return the original client ip based on `forwarded`,
    `x-forwarded-for` or `x-real-ip`. If HTTP headers are unavailable or
    untrusted, returns an empty string.

    :return: original client ip.
    """
    if not hasattr(self, "_remote_addr"):
        self._remote_addr = self.forwarded.get("for", "")
    return self._remote_addr
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some proxies or load balancers could hide original client ip. Mentioned headers could store this value.

For example, see documentation for [X-Forwarded-For](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-For) header

Answer (score 1):

`request.ip` only shows the address directly connecting Sanic, while `request.remote_addr` only shows a remote address given by a proxy (e.g. if you are [running behind Nginx](https://github.com/huge-success/sanic/blob/master/docs/sanic/nginx.rst)). You need to choose one depending on whether your application is running behind a proxy or not. To support both, use

```py
user_ip = request.remote_addr or request.ip
```